# How do I unlock the Guardian Frame Shift Drive Booster?

Tags: elite-dangerous, elite-dangerous-horizons

The Guardian Frame Shift Drive Booster is a Guardian module that provides a flat increase to jump range, up to a 10.5 LY boost for a class 5 booster. It's the most useful Guardian module in the game.

In order to unlock it, you need to bring a number of Guardian materials to a tech broker (1 blueprint segment, 21 power cells, and 21 technology components). The problem is, I don't have any idea where to begin finding these materials. How do I obtain all of the materials necessary to unlock the Guardian Frame Shift Drive Booster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You obtain Guardian materials at a Guardian Structure. This requires an SRV and a ship equipped for long-distance travel.

In order to obtain the Guardian Module Blueprint, you first find an ancient relic at the site (by shooting a "relic tower"), and scooping it up. Then locate the databank (a distinct raised platform near the center of the site), activate the two pylons near the databank by shooting them. With those pylons activated, a timer starts, and you activate all the other pylons (up to 6), then drop the relic in front of the databank and use your datalink scanner on the resulting sphere, and that gives you the blueprint.

The other materials you obtain by shooting destructible items at the site and scooping up the materials that drop.

Note that there will be Guardian skimmers that appear and shoot missiles at you. You'll need to destroy those with your SRV turret.

The easiest location is system HD 63154, planet B 3 A.

Canonn has a good guide: https://canonn.science/codex/guardian-structure/

A really good video guide: